# Frequency of worker dyno run on Heroku

Tags: heroku, worker

I have created one worker dyno in Heroku app that is supposed to execute cakephp command on its run. See Procfile code below:-

```
worker: app/Console/cake opportunity
```

What is the default frequency of this worker dyno execution? I have checked heroku logs that shows the above worker process executed at some intervals as below:-

> 2016-04-06T11:13:34.557478+00:00 app[worker.1]:
>
> 2016-04-06T11:13:34.557497+00:00 app[worker.1]:
>
> 2016-04-06T11:13:34.570029+00:00 app[worker.1]: Path: /app/app/
>
> ### 2016-04-06T11:13:34.570041+00:00 app[worker.1]:
>
> 2016-04-06T11:13:34.616102+00:00 app[worker.1]: entered shell--
>
> 2016-04-06T11:13:35.208536+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from
>   up to crashed

I need to execute the above worker dyno every minute. Do I need to use scheduler add-on for this in conjunction to the worker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I have came to know after further implementation is that, the worker process is just like a "daemon" process running on linux. So basically the frequency of worker dyno run is just everytime.

The process that executes on worker should be formed such so as to create a loop with some specific delay after each run.

Answer (score 0):

In cases where you need to use an specific frecuency, you must use the [clock process type](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/scheduled-jobs-custom-clock-processes#custom-clock-processes) instead of `worker`.

That way you can schedule jobs to be executed every minute.

Comment: So this means I just need to change the process type from **worker** to **clock** in app Procfile. Right?

Comment: No, it won't be enough. You'll have to refactor your process. Please read the doc I've posted in the answer.

Comment: I have gone through the doc. The example they provided is with node.js architecture which is not applicable in my case. What I have got is that worker process will also be required and clock process to specify the time for each worker run.

Comment: But I can see my worker process invoked even if I don't use any clock processes. Can you please suggest which default settings are causing that?